# how to change label color when intersecate with an image in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlabel

I have a Qlabel with white text on a black background. In this screen i create a white rectangle which change dimension, through:

```
QGraphicsRectItem* rect;
rect->setRect(0, START_HEIGHT, 0+variable, HEIGHT);
```

By calling a function which modify the value of "variable" and recreate the rectangle,I change its size.
This rectangle is white and when it happens to reach the label, this last one disappear (white on white).

**I'd like to know how can I turn black the text color inside the label when it intersecate the rectangle (only the intersection since if all the label change to black, only the part over the rectangle would be visible).**

Here an example i found on google (looking for PorterDuff which seems to do something similar on android). It is different but can be a good example to visualize what i would like to obtain.

[image]

Thanks in advance if you have some solution or some hints =)

**Edit**: Here a minimal and reproducible example

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->label->raise();
ui->label->setText("CCC");

//set scene
    scene= new QGraphicsScene();
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    ui->graphicsView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    ui->graphicsView->setStyleSheet("background: transparent;");
    ui->graphicsView->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);


timers = new QTimer(this);
connect(timers, &QTimer::timeout, this,&MainWindow::grow_my_child);
timers->start(10);
}
void MainWindow::grow_my_child()
{
static int x=0;
rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();

rect->setBrush(Qt::white);
rect->setPen(Qt::NoPen);

scene->addItem(rect);

rect->setVisible(true);
rect->setRect(0,0,0+x,200);
x++;

if(x ==500){
   timers->stop();
}
}
```

and the header:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <Qlabel>
#include <QGraphicsOpacityEffect>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPen>
#include <QFontDatabase>
#include <QSize>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QParallelAnimationGroup>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~MainWindow();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
QTimer * timers;
QGraphicsScene* scene;
QGraphicsRectItem* rect;
void grow_my_child();

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

In the .ui file there is only a label and a graphicview element (no name changed) and the background is black

The result once the rectangle reach the label is :
[image]

The text is "CCC" and i'd like to visualize that half black and half white

Comment: I added the example, in case other info is needed please ask and I will try to make things more clear

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a `QLabel` instead of `QGraphicsTextItem` ?

Comment: Not really, I'm new in QT, Can i solve my problem with QGraphicsTextItem?

Comment: If you use a `QGraphicsScene` it's better to use `QGraphicsItem` because it is designed for this. You absolutely want the 'CCC' completely white ? Beacause I have a solution but the text is a little bit gray du to raster op

Comment: If it is a bit gray it could be ok, actually my use case says it has to be white or similar, but it wants it is fully visible during the intersection. If you post it as an answer I could vote you as best response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own implemention to change the [`QPainter::compositionMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) of your item:

```cpp
class TextItem : public QGraphicsTextItem
{
public:
    TextItem(const QString &text, QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr)
        : QGraphicsTextItem(text, parent){ setZValue(100); }
    TextItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr)
        : QGraphicsTextItem(parent){ setZValue(100); }
private:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = 0) override {
        painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Difference);
        QGraphicsTextItem::paint(painter, option, widget);
    }
};
```

With this class, you have just to write some lines:

```cpp
// Add your rectangle
QGraphicsRectItem *rectitem = scene->addRect(-50, -50, 100, 50, QPen(Qt::white), Qt::white);
// Make your rectangle movable for test with your mouse
rectitem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);

// Add your text
TextItem *txtitem = new TextItem("CCC");
txtitem->setFont(QFont("Ubuntu", 50, 80));
txtitem->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::white);
scene->addItem(txtitem);
```

Now, by moving your rectangle, you will have something like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it works perfectly. I will study a bit what you did there but I really appreciate your help, thanks =). Have a good day